"Could not find part of path to System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" when installing nuget packages
I'm attempting to install some nuget packages into my project and keep getting an error that looks like this:
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\<path to my project>\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'

I have tried installing the nuget package for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe but that gave me the same issue.
I also tried downloading System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe directly from the nuget website and using gacutil on it but that did not change anything.

Which .NET version is your project using? And which version is the .nuget designed for? Recent versions of .NET shouldn't have an explicit reference to that package (since it's builtin).

Currently my project is using .NET Framework 4.7.2, which the first .nuget package I attempted to install claims to support.

I'm not sure what's going on here, but older .NET Framework versions are known to have some issues with recent nuget packages. I recommend updating to .NET 8.0.

I created a project target .NET Framework 4.7.2 and installed this packages , it worked well. For this issue, i would suggest you to check the following to troubleshoot.
1.Please check if  the path length exceeds the maximum limit (260 characters). If so, try to short the path or move your project to a directory with a shorter path. For example, move the project folder up nearer to c:\ and then
reinstall your package.
C:\<path to my project>\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll

2.Open you Registry Editor and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled and modify  LongPathsEnabled registry key  to 1 . Then reinstall your package.
3.Please check if you have the necessary permissions to access the directories involved.
C:\<path to my project>\packages\

4.Please check  package sources in NuGet.Config file are correctly configured.(Windows:%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesources
5.Do a quick test, create a new project in C:\project folder and install other package(e.g:Newtonsoft.Json) to see if the error occurs.
